# cocos2d how to make loading image last longer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i want to make my game loading image last longer(Default.png), how?

Comment: Can you provide some more info. of what is your question actually

Comment: i mean the splash image when launching the game. i want to make it 2 sec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can do is, in your application did finish launching method you can use NSThread to sleep for time interval of 2 sec.

Like this

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching
{
     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f];
}
```

But if you want to do some work behind the sense than you  can dispatch a custom queue to get the work done using Grand Central Dispatch.

Check the apple documentation on it.

Comment: no i just wanna show my beautiful image, one hr to make it. ^_^

Comment: just like to ask: where to add this function? under which file?

Comment: its in application delegate file.

Answer (score 0):

In the Appdelegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

sleep (3);

// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

The **sleep (3);** means that the loading screen (Default.png) will load/sleep for 3 seconds.
So actually you just have to put the seconds you want in the ().
For example 5 sec : **sleep(5);**